# Popover display in openlayer map

Tags: popover, openlayers-3

Popover in openlayer map, when it is appearing in the extreme ends, the content of the popover is not visible. It goes beyond the map area. Is there any way to adjust it accordingly as it will be visible inside the map and all its content get displayed other than scrolling??
[image]

Comment: Answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34224414/4640499.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [the (experimental) `autoPan` option](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.0/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html). It is disabled by default, so be sure to include to include the option when you create your Overlay for your popup, e.g.

```
var overlay = new ol.Overlay(({
  element: <your-element>,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  }
}));
```

Also see [the official OL3 popup example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.0/examples/popup.html).

If you do not like to use the autoPan option, then I would to refer to the comment given by Jonatas Walker.